# Interceptor prevents URL parameters from being passed to actions

Tags: struts2, interceptor

I've got a LoginInterceptor that runs before most actions and checks if the member is logged in or not. If it is, the page is shown, otherwise it is redirected to login page.

However I just noticed the interceptor "blocks" all URL parameters. Basically if there is an interceptor before an action, URL parameters for this action won't be passed to setters.

This is my interceptor:

```
public class LoginInterceptor extends AbstractInterceptor {
    public String intercept(final ActionInvocation invocation) throws Exception {
        final String REDIR = "loginRedirect";
        AuthenticationService auth = new AuthenticationService();
        if (auth.isMemberLoggedIn()) {
            return invocation.invoke();
        } else {
            return REDIR;
        }
    }
}
```

I suspect the `invocation.invoke()` invokes the action, but without the parameters.

What can I do about it?

UPDATE:

**AuthenticationService.isMemberLoggedIn()**

```
public boolean isMemberLoggedIn() {
    Map<String, Object> session = ActionContext.getContext().getSession();
    String username = (String) session.get("username");
    if (username != null) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

**struts.xml**

```
<package name="global" extends="struts-default">
    <interceptors>
        <interceptor name="loginInterceptor" class="community.interceptor.LoginInterceptor" />
    </interceptors>
    <global-results>
        <result name="loginRedirect" type="redirect">/members/login</result>
    </global-results>
</package>
```

Then each package extends `global` and I invoke them in each action:

```
<interceptor-ref name="loginInterceptor" />
```

Comment: Something is amiss here.  Could you share your code for `auth.isMemberLoggedIn()`?  Also, to be clear, your problem is not that the parameters are gone when the redirect occurs, but that they are gone when the action is invoked, correct?

Comment: That is correct. I don't see a need to share the content of `isMemberLoggedIn()` function. It works fine. It is just if the test is passed and `invocation.invoke()` is called the params "disappear".

Comment: I asked to see its contents since I suppose that it is accessing the HttpServletRequest in some manner, in which case it could be the culprit if not done correctly.  But if you are certain, then don;t include it.  Could you include your interceptor stack configuration from the struts.xml, though?  The missing params could also occur from the `params` interceptor not being included in the stack by accident.

Comment: Ugh, that might be the case: I did not include `params`... But shouldn't it be included by default?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If your interceptor stack does not include the `params` interceptor, then this problem will occur.  You should configure your stack something along the lines of this:

```
       <interceptors>
           <interceptor name="loginInterceptor" class="community.interceptor.LoginInterceptor" />
           <interceptor-stack name="customDefaultStack">
                <interceptor-ref name="i18n"/>
                <interceptor-ref name="loginInterceptor"/>
                <interceptor-ref name="prepare"/>
                <interceptor-ref name="modelDriven"/>
                <interceptor-ref name="fileUpload"/>
                <interceptor-ref name="checkbox"/>
                <interceptor-ref name="multiselect"/>
                <interceptor-ref name="params">
                    <param name="excludeParams">dojo\..*,^struts\..*,^session\..*,^request\..*,^application\..*,^servlet(Request|Response)\..*,parameters\...*</param>
                </interceptor-ref>
                <interceptor-ref name="conversionError"/>
                <interceptor-ref name="validation">
                    <param name="excludeMethods">input,back,cancel,browse</param>
                </interceptor-ref>
                <interceptor-ref name="workflow">
                    <param name="excludeMethods">input,back,cancel,browse</param>
                </interceptor-ref>
            </interceptor-stack>
        </interceptors>

        <default-interceptor-ref name="customDefaultStack"/>
```

Or, you can extend an out-of-the-box stack:

```
       <interceptors>
           <interceptor name="loginInterceptor" class="community.interceptor.LoginInterceptor" />
           <interceptor-stack name="customDefaultStack">
                <interceptor-ref name="loginInterceptor"/>
                <interceptor-ref name="defaultStack"/>
            </interceptor-stack>
        </interceptors>

        <default-interceptor-ref name="customDefaultStack"/>
```